# VB script + read files (only files with "log" name) and copy content files into one file.txt

Tags: vbscript

I have the following different files under C:\logs3

```
log1.txt
log2.txt
log3.txt
```

how to create with VB script , relevant code that create one file called:

```
log.general.txt
```

this VB script need to read all files content under log3 directory that have the name - log

```
as:  log1.txt  log2.test.txt log3.start.txt  mylog.txt  big.log.txt

But: not read the files as: test.txt  or ABBA.txt or CAR.txt
```

And copy the content of those files in to one file - log.general.txt - "also under log3 dir"

*** remark in case the file is empty then need to escape (continue to the next files)

for example

```
log1.txt:

111111
222222

log2.txt:

333333
444444


log3.txt

555555
666666

file.test.txt

777777
888888


 log.general.txt content: -> (Expected results from the VB script)

 111111
 222222
 333333
 444444
 555555
 666666
```

---

other example from linux: (to in order to explain my question)

```
cat log1.txt >> log.general.txt  
cat log2.txt >> log.general.txt
cat log3.txt >> log.general.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jon: Here's another solution in VBScript

```
Option Explicit

Const ForAppending = 8
Const ForReading   = 1
Const ForWriting   = 2

Dim oFS, oFolder, oFile, oRead, oWrite, oRegEx
Dim sContents, sDir, sFile
Dim iMatch

sDir  = "C:\log3\"
sFile = "log.general.txt"

Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFS.GetFolder(sDir)
Set oRegEx = New RegExp
With oRegEx
    .Pattern    = "log"
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global     = True
End With

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    iMatch = oRegex.Test(oFile.Name)

    If oFile.Name <> sFile AND iMatch = -1 Then
        Set oRead = oFS.OpenTextFile(oFile, ForReading)
        sContents = sContents & oRead.ReadAll & vbCrLf
        oRead.Close
    End If
Next

Set oWrite = oFS.OpenTextFile(sDir & sFile, ForAppending, True)
oWrite.WriteLine sContents
oWrite.Close

Set oRegEx = Nothing
Set oFS = Nothing
```

Comment: hi get file not found line-Set oWrite = oFS.OpenTextFile("C:\logs3\log.general.txt", ForAppending) 
but I have the logs3 dir ?

Comment: @jon: Please update that line to `Set oWrite = oFS.OpenTextFile(sInputDir & sOutputFile, ForAppending, True)` so it will create the file.

Comment: @stealthyninja now its work but the target of my question was to scan only files with log name , I have in logs directory also file name: test.txt and in this case I dont want to read this file , need to change the VB script in order to scan only files with log name , THX

Answer (score 0):

This works in VBScript:

```
Set oWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oWSH.Run ("%comspec% /c copy /b c:\docs\conc\log*.txt c:\docs\conc\onefile.txt")
```

Comment: its create the folwoing: 1111
22223333
4444 - why "\n" not after 2222 and why i get the char "" after 4444 ?

Comment: If the files do not terminate in a return character, it is not inserted. I am not sure about the character, do you mean space?

Comment: I dont have space in  my file

Comment: "some  " char is after 4444 why

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I missed the /b. I have added it now.

Comment: now i get: 1111
22223333
44441111
22223333 sorry its not as I need , we need each number in single line -;(
4444