# Combining .log files in C# by timestamp

Tags: c#, logging

My question is actually related to this post.

[VB script + read files (only files with "log" name) and copy content files into one file.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158120/vb-script-read-files-only-files-with-log-name-and-copy-content-files-into-o)

I want to do exactly what he has done (combine *.log files that I have a user browse for) however I need them to be inserted into the new log file time wise.  For example:

```
1.log (12:15:66)
2.log (10:09:33)
3.log (15:11:10)
```

I need the out put to be in the final.log file but in the order (2.log, 1.log, 3.log) because thats the order timewise they were created. I also will have different numbers of log files so it needs to either combine all in a directory or ask for each file until I don't specify anymore. I am going to be using C# also not VB like in the example.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Once the user has selected all of the logs that he wants to include, you can get the [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) for each file. Store those in a list and sort by timestamp. Then use a simple loop to copy each one to the output file.

Comment: Sorry I am fairly new to C# mind giving me an example even if only in pseudo code?

Comment: ok @jim-mischel i am stuck.  I am currently just trying to get the creation times for each of the files.  For some reason in the console it will output each of the file paths but when i use the same variable for the get creation time it is returning the creation time of the directory instead... here is the code I am using...

Comment: <code>
DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.

            if (result == DialogResult.OK) //Test Result
            {
                string dir = this.folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;

                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(f);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Created at " + File.GetCreationTime(f));
                    this.listBox1.Items.Add(f);
                }
</code>